# SWAP memory of my solaris server is used more than its threshold

Tags: solaris, swap

SWAP memory of my solaris server is used more than its threshold, is it possible to free some space by restarting the processes which are using most of SWAP memory?

```
$ swap -s
total: 10820256k bytes allocated + 453808k reserved = 11274064k used, 11911648k available
$ swap -l
swapfile         dev    swaplo blocks   free
/dev/md/dsk/d210 85,210 16     20972720 20971152
```

Comment: Why do you want to reduce swap usage?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: How are you measuring swap usage (there are different things that are named swap under Solaris) ? What is the threshold?

Comment: @AndrewHenle one of my process is using it and since it is crossing threshold i have a doubt that other processes which use this SWAP will get impacted.

Comment: @jlliagre i checked it using swap -s and swap -l commands

Comment: @jlliagre threshold id 50%

Comment: So can you post `swap -s` and `swap -l` output when that 50% threshold is reached?

Comment: @jlliagre below is the output
unixsup@********** $ swap -s
total: 10820256k bytes allocated + 453808k reserved = 11274064k used, 11911648k available

Comment: Please post `swap -l` output too. How much RAM do you have installed?

Comment: @jlliagre PLease see below details

****@*********$ swap -l
swapfile             dev  swaplo blocks   free
/dev/md/dsk/d210    85,210     16 20972720 20971152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using 800 KB of swap out of 10 GB (i.e. 0.008 %) which is insignificant. There is then probably nothing to worry about according to the reported statistics.

You might have a look to `/tmp` (or other `tmpfs` backed directories) to free some virtual memory.